# Where does Visual studio 2010 Checked-in items in Registry Editor?

Tags: tfs, registry, environment, save, checked

I'm using TFS.

My problem changing the path "Debug>Options and Settings>Source Control>Environment" where is the Registry Editor.

**example:**
i change check box "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer" in change the 
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\ShowDeletedItems data value change False in registry editor

but i change combo box" checked-in items -> Saving or Editing " the value. I am not found in registry editor. where is it in registry editor ?

Comment: any final solution with full source code in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values you are after, reside under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SourceControl".
Those settings are generic for VS and apply regardless of the SCM used. So, it makes sense these don't reside under "..\TeamFoundation..".
The following is a mapping of reg-value names against their representation in VS:
`GetFiles` >> Get everything when a solution or project is opened
`CheckInFiles` >> Check in everything when closing a solution or project
`SilentCheckOut` >> Display silent check out command in menus
`KeepCheckedOut` >> Keep items checked out when checking in
`SaveUncheckedOut` >> Checked-in items / Saving
`CheckOutOnEdit` >> Checked-in items / Editing
`AllowInMemoryEditing` >> Allow checked-in items to be edited
The items found in the dialog "Source Control"\"Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" obviously apply only when SCM is TFS.