# Get or Set SourceControl properties in VS2010

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-addins

I use VS 2010 and VS 2012, and TFS.

I am implementing a VS Addin (C#) and I need to get/set programmatically

> Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment->Checked-in item
>   behavior->On-Edit property. Value: Prompt for exclusive checkouts
>
> Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment->Checked-in item
>   behavior->On-Save property. Value: Prompt for check out
>
> Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server->
>   Get latest version of item on check out
>
> Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server->
>   Open Source Control Explorer to the most recent folder

I want to found an elegant solution for my problem and use interfaces or automation model.

Update:

References: [Where does Visual studio 2010 Checked-in items in Registry Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028703/where-does-visual-studio-2010-checked-in-items-in-registry-editor/10072855#10072855)